# How do I programmatically change a GroupBox Header font color?

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I programmatically change a GroupBox Header font color?

I have:

```
<GroupBox x:Name="gGBxOpenFile">
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <Label Foreground="Red">Open File</Label>
    </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

I can change the contents

```
gGBxOpenFile.Header = "Opened"
```

but don 't know how to change the font color to black.

Comment: If you want it to change when opening and closing then best would be to make a style that does the change based on that. If you want to change it separately then that’s another matter

Comment: Currently, when assigning `"Opened"` to the `GroupBox.Header` you are replacing the `Label` control with a plain `string`. You have to assign a new `Label`: `gGBxOpenFile.Header = new Label() { Content = "Opened", Foreground = Brushes.Black };`. Or follow the given [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59429962/3141792) which references the initial `Label` and change its appearance. If you prefer to use plain XAML you can consider to style the `Label` and use `Style.Triggers` to manipulate the appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a name to the label

```
<Label x:Name="myLabel" Foreground="Red">Open File</Label>
```

Change the color

```
myLabel.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
```

And can change the content via myLabel

```
myLabel.Content = "Opened";
```

No need to name the GroupBox.  This works.